# 'flutterfire configure' exits with an error that git i missing in my path. Do I need git installed to use flutterfire?

Tags: flutter, git, firebase

I have an app that has been working perfectly until to day. After som updates of plugins, I've encountered an error related to Firebase.initializeApp();

This function is called like this;

```
main() async { 
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    ....
}
```

For some reason this call throws an error:

```
PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
```

After searching a solution for some hours, I've come across a solution that looks like this

```
main() async { 
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
    ....
}
```

but for this to work, I need an autogenerated file called 'firebase_options.dart'.

This file is generated using firebase_cli and 'flutterfire configure'. This should, as far as i've understood, work on an already excisting app.

The problem is that the 'flutterfire configure' command throws this error

```
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.
```

Do I need to install git to get this to work?

This solution to configure an app has existed for years. Any idea why I suddenly has this problem? I suspect that updating firebase_core to the latest version did not help...

The old manual way to do this still works, but then I need to hard code Firebase-Options like this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(    
  options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "XXX",
    appId: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX",
    projectId: "XXX",
  ),
);
```

And I guess this will be to solution if git is needed to use the 'new and simple way' to implement firebase with flutter...

Answer (score 0):

After struggeling with the standalone binary for windows for hours, I installed firebase cli through the npm/nvm option and git.

After this I had to reauthenticate using

```
firebase login --reauth
```

and everything worked.